# Document Cleanup tool in sharepoint

Tags: 2010

We have thousands and thousands of documents on sharepoint many of which are old and obsolete.  I was wondering whether there was a tool that you can point at our intranet that will go through sharepoint and flag any documents that havent been modified since a certain date.

Answer (score 2):

Within SharePoint you can create an [information management policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms499244.aspx).

> An information management policy is a set of rules that govern the
>   availability and behavior of a certain type of important content.
>   Policy enables administrators to control and evaluate who can access
>   information, how long to retain information, and how effectively
>   people are complying with the policy. The most common creators and
>   enforcers of policy are compliance officers, records managers, IT
>   staff, and others who are responsible for managing risk.

For documents you can create retention policies in several ways:

- You can create a retention policy definition within your site collection, then apply that policy to content types throughout the site.
- You can create a retention policy that’s associated with a content type that’s defined in the root of the site collection.
- You can create a retention policy that’s associated with a local content type that has been applied to a list or library.
- You can create a retention policy directly on a list or library itself.

When creating a retention policy you can add stages. Within your stage you can say for example move all documents that are not modified within 1 year to the recycly bin or to a record center.

For example

[image: Stage property]

Comment: its best to add retention policy in this case

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of.
However, you can run a powershell script ([like this one](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/08/getting-an-inventory-of-all-sharepoint-documents-using-windows-powershell/#comments)) against your entire farm and export an inventory of your documents to a csv file. Opening it in Excel and filtering by date, as a first step you will be able to identify those that are older than a certain date.
You might as well modify the script to move them somewhere else or delete them altogether.

Here's the script found in the aforementioned link:

```
function Get-DocInventory() {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
    foreach ($spService in $farm.Services) {
        if (!($spService -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService])) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($webApp in $spService.WebApplications) {
            if ($webApp -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication]) { continue }

            foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) {
                foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
                    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
                        if ($list.BaseType -ne "DocumentLibrary") {
                            continue
                        }
                        foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                            $data = @{
                                "Web Application" = $webApp.ToString()
                                "Site" = $site.Url
                                "Web" = $web.Url
                                "list" = $list.Title
                                "Item ID" = $item.ID
                                "Item URL" = $item.Url
                                "Item Title" = $item.Title
                                "Item Created" = $item["Created"]
                                "Item Modified" = $item["Modified"]
                                "File Size" = $item.File.Length/1KB
                            }
                            New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                        }
                    }
                    $web.Dispose();
                }
                $site.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}
Get-DocInventory | Out-GridView
#Get-DocInventory | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path c:\inventory.csv
```